# Changing datatype of a key in a object

Tags: javascript, database, postgresql

I have some object that was returned from my database. When i build up my table, these are the dtypes that i declared:

1. festivalId = BIGINT
2. performanceId = BIGINT
3. startTime = TIME
4. endTime = TIME

When i wanted to extract some records with a specific performanceId, my query looks something like this:

```sql
SELECT performanceId, to_char(startTime, 'HH24MI') AS startTime, to_char(endTime, 'HH24MI') AS endTime FROM Performance WHERE festivalId = $1
```

And the entire result returned from postgresql was concated into an object.

Right now the problem is that my javascript for my middleware is reading each `performanceId` that is found in each object(meaning each unique performanceId) as a string instead of a integer type.
*e.g. performanceId 1234567890 is printed out as "1234567890" instead of 1234567890.*

Is there anyway that i can convert performanceId output as a integer?

I tried to convert it to a integer when doing my sql `SELECT` statement,

```sql
SELECT CAST(performanceId AS INTEGER) AS performanceId, to_char(startTime, 'HH24MI') AS startTime, to_char(endTime, 'HH24MI') AS endTime FROM Performance WHERE festivalId = $1
```

but i realise its different as there is a different acceptance range for INTEGER and BIGINT.

I don't know if my above post was misleading or not, so i decided to put some dummy output here:

This is the unintended output:

```js
{
  "result": [
    {
      "performanceid": "9999999999",
      "starttime": "0900",
      "endtime": "1200"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is the expected output:

```js
{
  "result": [
    {
      "performanceid": 999999999,
      "starttime": "0900",
      "endtime": "1200"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [JS BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) is fairly new, but it's also not part of the [JSON standard](https://www.json.org/json-en.html).

Accordingly, your output is correct, because while a string can contain any amount of digits/chars, a JSON with `9007199254740991n` as value would likely fail all over the place.

One way to to fix this, is to use a `JSON.parse` revival function, and return whatever you like when the key is `performanceid`

```
JSON.parse(data, (k, v) => k == 'performanceid' ? BigInt(v) : v);
```

You are, at this point, in charge of being sure the browser/JS engine is compatible with `BigInt`, and eventually provide a fallback if it's not (likely keeping it as a string).

If you are using `fetch(data).then(b => b.json())` you should also bypass it and use `fetch(data).then(b => b.text()).then(data => JSON.parse(data, reviver))` instead, so that your fetch operation will produce the desired outcome.